# Create a list in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples

Trying to create a list called `monthDetails` that has 13 items. The first item is the year, for example 2015, and the remaining 12 items are tuples that contain the months as shown below:

For example January would be:

```
('JANUARY', [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4',
              ...   ' 30', ' 31', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '])
```

The first entry is the month name and the second entry is the days.

How do I create the primary list and then add the desired data to the other 12 tuples in the primary list?

Comment: What are those empty (spaces only) strings in list?

Comment: Empty spaces at the beginning and end of the month because not every month starts on sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a list inside a tuple inside a list:

```
year = [
  ('JANUARY', [' ', '1', ... ' 30', ' 31', ' ']),
  ('MAY', [' ', '1', ... ' 30', ' 31', ' '])
]

print year  ## the whole thing
print year[0]  ## ('January', [' ', '1', ... '31', ' '])
print year[0][0]  ## 'January'
print year[0][1]  ## [' ', ' ', ... ' 31', ' ', ...]
```

One of the many problems with this approach is that you can't make an assignment to a tuple once it's created.  So you can't "*create the primary list and then add the desired data to the other 12 tuples in the primary list*".  You have to create the inner lists before creating the tuple.  Once you have the tuple you can add it to the outer list.

The biggest problem, of course, is hard-coding this kind of data.  You can (and should) use a date library, such as python's datetime.
You can create a date object whenever you need info about a particular date:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
print d.strftime("%A"), d.year, d.month, d.day

d = datetime.date(2015, 1, 31)
print d.strftime("%A %x")
```

You can step forward through a month (such as for printing out a calendar):

```
m = 1
d = 1
date = datetime.date(2015, m, d)
while date.month == m:
    wd = date.isoweekday()  ## Mon = 1, ... Sun = 7

    ## do whatever you need
    print date.strftime("%A %x")

    d += 1
    date = date.replace(day=d)  ## new date with the next day
```

I would encourage you to look through https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects

There are even more efficient ways to do it, but this is straightforward and hopefully understandable to you.